# Stub a ES6 EventEmitter class function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, stubbing

I have a dependency class that extends EventEmitter and I need to test how a function that uses this dependency will react based on the events that it fires. How do you stub a function of a EventEmitter class?

**Dependency Class**

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class FooBar extends EventEmitter {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.doingSomething = false;
  }

  doSomething() {
    if (this.doingSomething === false) {
      this.doingSomething = true;
      this.emit('startedDoingSomething');
    }
    else {
      this.emit('alreadyDoingSomething');
    }
  }
}

module.exports = FooBar;
```

**Dependent Module Under Test**

```
let Foobar = require('FooBar');
let fooBar = new FooBar();

exports.myFunction = () => {
  // Set up listeners
  fooBar.once('startedDoingSomething', () => {
    fooBar.removeAllListeners();
    // Some functionality
    console.log('Started Doing Something');
  });

  fooBar.once('alreadyDoingSomething', () => {
    fooBar.removeAllListeners();
    // Some functionality
    console.log('Already Doing Something');
  });

  // Call the event-emitting function
  fooBar.doSomething();
};

// Other functions that use fooBar
```

I'm using Sinon in order to create a stub, but I haven't been able to stub the class functions that emit events effectively. I modeled my test off of [[Feature request] stub emits](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1045) but had to make some modifications since the event emitter dependency being stubbed is a class.

**Test**

```
let chai = require('chai');
let sinon = require('sinon');
let FooBar = require('FooBar');
let dependentModule = require('./dependentModule');

describe('Dependent Module', () => {
  it('alreadyDoingSomething', () => {
    sinon.stub(FooBar.prototype, 'pause', () => {
      FooBar.prototype.emit('alreadyDoingSomething');
    });

    // Assertion statements here
    expect(dependentModule.myFunction()).to...
  });
});
```

This approach does not actually emit an event even though the stub function is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 13 in Test, it calls `dependentModule.myFunction()`

Then it jumps to line 5 in Dependent Module Under Test

Then in line 19 in Dependent Module Under Test, it calls `fooBar.doSomething()`

Then it jumps to line 12 in Dependency Class, there `this.doingSomething` is false, so it emits `startedDoingSomething`.

Then it jumps to line 7 in Dependent Module Under Test, it calls `fooBar.removeAllListeners();`, which means the event handler registered at line 34 of the same file is also removed.

Is this inteded?

Now assume `fooBar.removeAllListeners` in line 7 Dependent Module Under Test is commented out.

And after line 13 in Test, it calls `FooBar.prototype.pause` which in turn calls `FooBar.prototype.emit('alreadyDoingSomething');`

The problem is that when `FooBar.prototype.emit` is called, `this` in the context is not equal to `fooBar` declared in line 2 in Dependent Module Under Test. (It is equal to `FooBar.prototype`)

So `FooBar.prototype.emit('alreadyDoingSomething');` won't trigger event handler defined in line 12 in Dependent Module Under Test.

We will need to find a way to call `fooBar.emit('alreadyDoingSomething')`.

But that's impossible, because `fooBar` is never exported, unless some library like [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) is used.

Now assume we add `exports.fooBar = fooBar;` to the end of Dependent Module Under Test.

And we also change line 9 in Test to `this.emit('alreadyDoingSomething')` This is important, because we need the context when emit is called needs to be the instance, in our case `fooBar`.

And now in Test, when `dependentModule.fooBar.pause()` is called, that triggers a alreadyDoingSomething.

Now you should see `Already Doing Something` in your console.

Comment: Yes - the removeAllListeners() call on line 7 is intentional, as it prevents myFunction from hanging around after a single event was emitted. In this particular case, I only care about the first event that was emitted but need to handle all cases.

Your suggested exports fix does work -- even without commenting the removeAllListeners() calls -- but it's unfortunate that there's no way to make this work with just the constructor instead of the exact instance of the class.